# ¿Cómo validar matriculas mediante expresiones regualres?

Tags: javascript

tengo un este código en el que uno de los campos es validar una matricula de coche, concretamente mediante este formato ‘MU-XXXX-YYY’ donde XXXX son 4 dígitos numéricos
y YYY son letras de la A a la Z en mayúsculas.
Pero no para de aparecerme este error:

> " Invalid regular expression: /^[A-Z]*-\d{4}*-[A-Z]{3}$/: Nothing to
> repeat
> at new RegExp ()
> at validar (mensaje.js:70:21)"

Aquí dejo el código.

html:

```
<p><label for="matricula">Matricula:</label><input type="text" id="c5" name="color"
        placeholder="Matricula del coche formato MU-XXXX-YYY"></p>
```

y javascript:

```
  var matricula = new RegExp("^[A-Z]*-\\d{4}*-[A-Z]{3}$");
var valormatricula = document.getElementById('c5').value;
if (!matricula.test(valormatricula)) {
    if (valid) {
        document.getElementById('c5').focus();
    }
    valid = false;
    error += 'Erro en la matricula el formato debe ser ‘MU-XXXX-YYY’ donde XXXX son 4 dígitos numéricos y YYY son letras de la A a la Z en mayúsculas';

}
```

Comment: No se yo si deberias reinventar la rueda en este caso. El campo `input` permite patrones con expresiones regulares, como puedes ver aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: ¿Pero como hacer render del error? Valida el input y no permite el submit del formulario, pero el tiene un error personalizado.

Comment: El problema creo que está en el * que está después del `{4}` pues el 4 ya es un cuantificador, y le estas poniendo el * luego del cuantificador. Quitaselo y dejalo así `^[A-Z]*-\\d{4}-[A-Z]{3}$`

Comment: @Pipe Si tenias razon, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dice `Pipe` en [su comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/513729/c%c3%b3mo-validar-matriculas-mediante-expresiones-regualres/513796#comment913085_513729), el problema se debe al `*` que has puesto junto al `{4}`.

Una `RegEx` que se ajusta a tu necesidad podría ser la siguiente:

```
^[A-Z]{2}-\d{4}-[A-Z]{3}$
```

Donde:

- `^`: La cadena empieza con...
- `[A-Z]{2}`: dos letras mayusculas de la A a la Z
- `-`: carater guión medio
- `\d{4}`: cuatro números del 0 al 9
- `-`: carater guión medio
- `[A-Z]{3}`: tres letras mayusculas de la A a la Z
- `$`: La cadena termina

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var matricula = /^[A-Z]{2}-\d{4}-[A-Z]{3}$/;
var c5 = document.getElementById('c5');

c5.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  let valormatricula = c5.value;
  if (matricula.test(valormatricula)) {
    console.log('Exito!');
  } else {
    console.error('Erro en la matricula el formato debe ser ‘MU-XXXX-YYY’ donde XXXX son 4 dígitos numéricos y YYY son letras de la A a la Z en mayúsculas')
  }
});
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="matricula">Matricula:</label>
  <input type="text" id="c5" name="color" placeholder="Matricula del coche formato MU-XXXX-YYY">
</p>
```